# Trying to add ids for anchor tag at the time of creating li tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/73rpubfd/ working fine. Pasting the code here for reference:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="test">
</ul>

var items=['a1','a2'];

var arrayLength = items.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   
   $("#test").append("<li><a>"+items[i]+"</a></li>");
    
}
```

My requirement is to insert an id for the  tag and part of the id value will be coming from the the array values .

So, I would expect it to be like this inside the loop :

```
$("#test").append("<li><a id="tab_"+items[i]+">"+items[i]+"</a></li>");
```

And basically it would probably look something like this after inspecting the li element in the developer tools of chrome.

```
<li><a id="tab_a1">a1</a></li>
<li><a id ="tab_a2">a2</a></li>
```

But as soon as I try to define `id = tab_" it starts complaining. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Mismatched quotes. Try a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): ``$("#test").append(`<li><a id="tab_${items[i]}">${items[i]}</a></li>);``

Comment: No-one else mentioned - just use the other quote:  `.append("<li><a id='tab"+i+"'>..")` or `.append('<li><a id="tab'+i+'">..')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an issue with the format of the html props needing double quotes. The best way to create complex strings is to use template literals like so:

```js
$("#test").append(`<li><a id="tab_${items[i]}">${items[i]}</a></li>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes if they appear within another quotes.

```js
$("#test").append("<li><a id=\"tab_\">"+items[i]+"</a></li>");
```

The other solution is to use backticks:

```js
$("#test").append(`<li><a id="tab_">${items[i]}</a></li>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can contain placeholders indicated by `${expression}` and useful for string interpolation

```js
var items=['a1','a2'];

var arrayLength = items.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   const li = `<li><a id="tab_${items[i]}">${items[i]}</a></li>`;
   $("#test").append(li);
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="test">
</ul>
```

Or in one line and without jQuery

Use array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and transform each array item to `li` html and lastly [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) by empty.

```
const html = items.map(item => `<li><a id="tab_${item}">${item}</a></li>`).join('');

$("#test").append(html);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.